# Looping in Handling Exception

Tags: c#, loops, exception

I have made a simple program. I want to add loop for `try`, `catch` statement, so if the user write input, he gets and error message and the program let him to write again.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter The File Location");
string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
try
{
    string content = File.ReadAllText(userValue);
    Console.WriteLine(content);            
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There was a Problem");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}  
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There was a Problem");
    Console.WriteLine("Could not find the Directory");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: My Question is that I want to Add loop , So when user Give wrong Input (File not Found or Directory not found) then the program let the user to Give input again and same thing happen again .

Comment: The loop has nothing to do with your try / catch - the loop will be your application flow. Also consider whether it really is an exception that the file or directory does not exists - instead consider just validating the input and showing messages.

Comment: I was just going to post what @AllanS.Hansen just said. So instead I'll provide some MSDN links - consider using [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Directory.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of throwing exception as throwing exception is expensive and considered [anti-pattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why)

Comment: @PawełHemperek - good idea but FileExists() cannot be made concurrency-safe. You still need a try/catch.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks for pointing that out - I didn't realise this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your code inside a `while` loop, that repeats the code until a successful operation has been completed.

```
var success = false;
while (success == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter The File Location");
    string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText(userValue);
        Console.WriteLine(content);            
        success = true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There was a Problem");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }  
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There was a Problem");
        Console.WriteLine("Could not find the Directory");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are able to check for invalid input, it's usually best to do that rather than let an exception happen.
In your case you can check File.Exists(...) and/or Directory.Exists(...) based on the user's input.
You could make those the conditions of your loop statement, so continue to prompt the user until they use a correct directory and file.
However, I would suggest that this is not necessarily the best user experience, as you are expecting them to *know* a valid file and directory, which they may not. Certainly you should provide a way for them to exit out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a while construct with a specified condition when the user input is done (when you detect an Enter keypress, or have a complete command or otherwise).
Then you can loop while that condition is not met (and there is no unrecoverable error), and use your code above to check for user errors and print messages when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loop. Yuo can use Recursive function.
Try this:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/4NR26P

Comment: I think using recursion is not the best idea - you're asking for `StackOverflowException` with this.

Comment: He could add a question on error and ask "Do you want to retry?" if user answer yes than call the function again, otherwise exit. Recursion != StackOverflowException if well done :-D

Comment: You can achieve this with `while` loop as well.

Comment: sure, but is more elegant IMHO with recursion. Also with loop you can rease the StackOverflowException :-D

Comment: How in this case you would end up with `StackOverflowException`? With `while` loop you are using only one stack frame. Try to write simple application, which increments value of `int i` until `int.MaxValue` in iterative and recursive way. You'll see that in iterative approach you won't end up with `StackOverflowException`, but with recursion you will.

Comment: @Alberto: I think it is possible to reach StackOverflowException with your code, if I'm not mistaken. Consider that there might be 1000,2000 or more invalid user entries. For each input, exception will be thrown and method called again, which would eventually lead to SO Exception. Unless I've missed something.

Comment: @Jure: yes, but the developer can add a question (as my comment above) before automaticly retry, so the user will stop after 5-10 errors (I don't believe a normal user arrive to 1000-2000 or more entries) :-)